# Display one character give number of times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need to add a character "A" incremented number of times to the end of stor_Id if qty <=90.

So after returning a query I should get Something like:

```
Stor_Id  
7131  
7066  
7067a  
8042aa  
7896aaa  
6380aaaa
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more detail on how you determine how many 'a's should be appended?

Comment: This has to be  the first time I see such a requirement. May I ask why?

Comment: @Abe, if query sees qty<90 first time it adds one "a" to the corresponding stor_id, if query sees qty<90 the second time it adds two "a", etc..  @Cularis, nope that's a secret :)

Comment: So if the row with rank 6 was changed to rank 100 it would have the same number of 'a's after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Rank is also an incrementing number.  If not then I'm not sure how to have a number increment for each row your operating on.

Something like this should work (not tested, but should be almost there)

```
UPDATE U
SET stor_Id = stor_Id + REPLICATE('A',rank)
FROM MyTable AS U
WHERE qty <= 90
```

Comment: +1, I would only suggest doing `rank - 2` since that appears to be what he is wanting.

Comment: let me try it. We can have a rank using this command: rank() OVER

Comment: @Treborbob, I don't understand your comment.  I am talking about replacing the `rank` in your code with `rank-2`, not changing the `where` clause

Comment: @Abe, sorry I see what you mean now, 1st one with an 'a' only has one 'a', i stand corrected :)

Comment: Seems like you would get a's on every record, incrementing by 1 from the get go

Comment: @Nicklamort Only where qty <= 90. However my code wont produce the exact result described as the 1st one with qty <= 90 has a rank of 3, so it would get 3 a's, but I think the OP has worked around that.